# Why am I unable to see multiple plots appear with a for loop?

Tags: r, plot, bioconductor

This is my code which is part of a larger script.

```
for(d1 in names(survD)){
survfit1 <- survfit(Surv(time=survD[[d1]][,"time"],
                                    event=survD[[d1]][,"death"],type='right')~1)

png(paste(survPath,"/surv_",d1,".png",sep=""))
plot(survfit1,xlab="Years",ylab="Survival probability",xmax=xmax1)

}
```

I don't have a good idea of what this code does yet, so I'm trying to look at each individual plot to see what it is. The problem is, whenever I run this in the R command line in the terminal in linux, nothing appears. I have to use dev.off() multiple times and then rerun this code:

```
plot(survfit1)
```

for something to appear. How can I see all the plots?

Comment: Get rid of this line `png(paste(survPath,"/surv_",d1,".png",sep=""))` then they will print to your graphic device. They'll all come up in rapid succession, however, so you'll have to go back through them. Or you can pause the loop by adding `readline()` somewhere in your loop.

Comment: `png()`, `jpeg()`, etc... ((check `?png`) should also end with a `dev.off()`? I guess the purpose of the snippet is to save multiple plots to multiple files, so you could then see them with an image viewer browsing their directoryl

Comment: solely removing that lines doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is really what you want:

```
for(d1 in names(survD)){
  survfit1 <- survfit(Surv(time=survD[[d1]][,"time"],
                           event=survD[[d1]][,"death"],type='right')~1)
  x11()  ## open up new graphical window for each plot (to avoid overwriting)
  plot(survfit1,xlab="Years",ylab="Survival probability",
       xmax=xmax1, main = d1)  ## use different titles to distinguish those plots
  }
```

This will produce plots on normal graphical windows.

---

If you want to use the original code, you'd better do this way:

```
for(d1 in names(survD)){
  survfit1 <- survfit(Surv(time=survD[[d1]][,"time"],
                           event=survD[[d1]][,"death"],type='right')~1) 
  png(paste(survPath,"/surv_",d1,".png",sep=""))
  plot(survfit1,xlab="Years",ylab="Survival probability",xmax=xmax1)
  dev.off()
  }
```

Then, have a look at the directory given by `getwd()`. All the plots are saved in `png` files.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Sys.sleep(.1) might help during the for loop. Maybe try:

```
for(d1 in names(survD)){
survfit1 <- survfit(Surv(time=survD[[d1]][,"time"],
                                    event=survD[[d1]][,"death"],type='right')~1)
Sys.sleep(.1)
png(paste(survPath,"/surv_",d1,".png",sep="", collapse="))
plot(survfit1,xlab="Years",ylab="Survival probability",xmax=xmax1)
dev.off()
```

}